# Select drop down triggers multiple page reloads

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a mvc grid and a select list.  When the user makes a selection the on change even fires posts data populates the grid and shows show additional links. There is an addition text box to filter data. If the user clicks one of the links I grab the selected value of the list store that in localstorage, I get the search string from the text box and also store that in local storage then nav to a different page.

Now the issue comes when the user clicks the browser back button after they have viewed some data and want to look at the grid page again.  I grab the values from local storage put them in the select list and text box and trigger the submit to redisplay the data they filtered on.  But that keeps constantly reposting.  Any suggestions

Thanks in advance

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

$('select').on('change', function (event) {
    if ($("option:selected", this).val() != "-1") {
        
        $(event.target).parents('form').trigger("submit");
        localStorage.setItem('qName', $('#qId option:selected').text());
        localStorage.setItem('eId', $("option:selected", this).val());
        
    }
});


if (localStorage.getItem('searchString') !== null) {
        $('option:selected', localStorage.getItem('eId')).val();
        $('form').trigger("submit");        
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.trigger( event [, extraParameters ] )](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) in order to distinguish if the event comes from a function or another. Moreover, you need to add a submit handler for your form in order to prevent default action if the submit comes from the undesired function:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e, extraParams) {
```

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(e, extraParams) {
    if (extraParams == true) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

$('select').on('change', function (event) {
    if ($("option:selected", this).val() != "-1") {

        localStorage.setItem('qName', $('#qId option:selected').text());
        localStorage.setItem('eId', $("option:selected", this).val());
        $(event.target).parents('form').trigger("submit");

    }
});

if (localStorage.getItem('searchString') !== null) {
    $('option:selected', localStorage.getItem('eId')).val();
    $('form').trigger("submit", true);
    //                         extraParams
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form>
    <select>
        <option value="1">one</option>
        <option value="2">two</option>
    </select>
</form>
```